# Apply CSS style to <div>

Tags: html, css

My problem is with the below html

```
<div class="editor-container">
   <div class="editor-row curFocus">
       <div class="editor-label">
           <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
       </div>
       <div class="editor-field">
          <input class="text-box single-line valid" id="FirstName" 
                name="FirstName" type="text" value="Nancy" maxlength="20">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When the user selects the input field, I add class "curFocus" to the outer div via some javascript to highlight both label and the input field.

My css is -

```
.editor-container {
    border: thin solid #444444;
    display: table; width: 100%;
 }
.editor-row {
  width: 100%; display: table-row;
}
.editor-label {
  padding-left: .4em; width: 40%;
}
.editor-label, .editor-field {
   padding-right: .4em; padding-bottom: .2em; padding-top: .2em;
   display: table-cell;
 }
 .curFocus {
   border: 2px solid #05365b;
   background-color: #d3e5f2;
   margin: 3px; padding: 3px;
  }
```

My problem is that while using debuggers in Chrome 12 and IE9, they both show the border settings being applied to the outer div.  But, when viewing the form, neither browser display's the specified border.  All other css settings work correctly.  I also tried changing definition of ".curFocus" to ".curFocus div".  But this applied the style to each of the nested div's also, but did display borders on all of the divs.

While I'm not a CSS expert, it is not obvious why this shouldn't work.

---

Edit
Here is jsfiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/KmsF5/1/.  While testing this it does work correctly in IE9 if in IE7 compatibly mode.  Otherwise, it does not display correctly.
Sorry about not including link, still getting use to fact that jsfiddle even exists.

Comment: Give us a jsfiddle or other demo.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/EzPBa/  - edit this and lets see

Comment: @ppumkin - It appears to work correctly, but when I put my link up (same time as you did), I found that while it appears to be working, what it is actually displaying is the outer most div for class=".editor-container"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I can tell you what's causing it, but I can't tell you why. Elements with `display: table-row;` can't have a border applied to them. You can apply the border to the `table-cell` children of the `.curFocus` element, but not the `table-row` itself.

Again, no idea why this silly rule exists, but you can fix your problem with some CSS:

```
.curFocus {
   background-color: #d3e5f2;
   margin: 3px; padding: 3px;
}

.curFocus>div {
   border: 2px solid #05365b;
   border-width: 2px 0px;  /* top and bottom border for all the table-row's immediate children (table-cells) */
}

.curFocus>div:first-child {
    border-width: 2px 0px 2px 2px; /* left border for the leftmost table-cell */
}

.curFocus>div:last-child {
    border-width: 2px 2px 2px 0px; /* right border for the rightmost table-cell */
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/d772N/

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with your characterization that the rule appears to be silly.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is your display type on the .editor-row. `display: table-row;` Remove that and the problem will go away. Plus I don't think that all browsers support `display: table-row;` very well.

Answer (score 0):

You might need a higher CSS specificity, as it is ambiguous which CSS styles will apply with the current definitions.

Try `div.curFocus` rather than `.curFocus div` for the class definition to apply the style to the div with that class name rather than its `div` children.

Comment: Probably because OP already covered this in his post, and it's not the issue, and he's not using `.curFocus div`

Comment: @Wesley Murch - From question:  "I also tried changing definition of '.curFocus' to '.curFocus div'."  This will apply styles to the children of the curFocus element, not the curFocus element, as it appears this is what he meant to do.

Comment: I have no idea why you're pinging me, I have nothing to do with it - just thought I'd try to explain someone else's downvote. Read the question and code again. Did you test your solution? Feel free to correct or delete your answer.

Comment: I don't think this solution needs to be changed or updated, as it points out a flaw in hughes's testing when he tried the wrong CSS selector in attempt to increase the specificity.  He himself says he is new to CSS, so I thought I'd point this out as a potential problem.  Clearly, the solution turned out to be related to the `display: table-row;` instead, but I entered this before seeing that answer.  Oh well...(sigh)...